# How do I return label value from application window in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I have written windows application in C#.

I want to select a file folder and do some searching in that directory. The problem is that I can't extract this path to a string variable.

This is method for retrieving folderPath from my browse folders window. (in `public partial class Form1 : Form`)

```
    private void folderPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.labelPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            // this piece of code works fine
        }
    }
```

`this.labelPath.Text` is my path to directory.

Now I tried creating method:

```
    public static string getLabelPath()
    {
        return this.labelPath.Text;
    }
```

And in my main program:

```
    string basePath = Form1.getLabelPath();
```

But I cannot do this, because of `Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer ...\Form1.cs 37`

How do I return this labelPath.Text value? I believe I could call something like myform.labelpath; if only I had reference to Form1 object, but in my program Windows Application is initialized using:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Just `new Form1();`, `not Form1 myform= Form1();`. I don't know how to do this the right way.

Comment: Don't make `getLabelPath()` static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the `static` keyword:

```
public string getLabelPath()
{
    return this.labelPath.Text;
}
```

And use a `Form` instance:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

or you create a static instance:

```
static Form1 form;
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    form = new Form1();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Then you can call `string basePath = form.getLabelPath();`

Comment: `Main();` is static, so using `Form1 form;` outside and in `form = new Form1();` inside gives an error.

Comment: Sorry I oversaw that. I think you need to place "Form1 form" inside the "Main" function.

Comment: I added another solution. Look at the question

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just directly using OpenFileDialog from Main()?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            ofd.Title = "Please select a File to Blah blah bleh...";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = ofd.FileName;

                // ... now do something with "fileName"? ...        
                Application.Run(new Form1(fileName));
            }
        }
    }
```